# Deployed Google Apps Script Add-on only works through individual install

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I made an Apps Script for Google Sheets and published it as an editor Add-on for my company domain. Its one custom function and when I did an individual install for myself it works fine. And when anyone else in the org does an individual install it works fine. However when installing it for the whole company via Admin Console, the Add-on doesn't work and gives the following error `unknown function`. So I want to know what am I missing that is preventing this Add-on from working.

Comment: This might be worth reading: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2017/12/07/6-deadly-sins-google-apps-script-add-on/

Comment: Might be an issue of the add-on not being enabled. Could you share the link of the published add-on?

Comment: @Cooper thanks for the read, I really found it useful for other purposes, but it didn't help with my issue at all hehe. Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after like 5 hours of not understanding what's going and not being able to find the solution. I figured it out. In the spreadsheet I had to go to **Add-Ons** -> **Manage Add-Ons** and on the Add-On I made there were the **3 vertical dots** (options) and right clicking reveals a panel that says ***"Use in this document"***. Though a minor inconvenience - every time someone in the org creates a new spreadsheet and wants to use functions from the plug-in, they will have to do just that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that answer.